# Повторение переменных в маршрутах laravel

Tags: php, laravel, маршрутизация

Есть URL, к которому надо прийти: `site.com/catalog/cat1/cat2/25-rose-1.html`, где `cat1 cat2` - это категории, `25-rose` - это алиас товара, а `1` - это его ID.

Делаю вот так:

```
Route::get('catalog/{parentCategory}/{childrenCategory}/{productAlias}-{productId}.html', function($parentCategory, $childrenCategory, $productAlias, $productId){
echo 'Parent category: '. $parentCategory .
    ' Children category: '.$childrenCategory.
    ' Product alias: '.$productAlias.
    ' Product ID: '.$productId;
});
```

Но результат получается такой:

```
Parent category: cat1 
Children category: cat2 
Product alias: 25 
Product ID: rose-1
```

Вопрос: каким образом сделать, чтобы ID товара Laravel смотрел по последнему `-` в ссылке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете уточнить в маршруте что в параметре `productAlias` используется значение по типу `25-rose` с помощью [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints):

```
Route::get('catalog/{parentCategory}/{childrenCategory}/{productAlias}-{productId}.html', function($parentCategory, $childrenCategory, $productAlias, $productId) {
    echo 'Parent category: '. $parentCategory .
        ' Children category: '.$childrenCategory.
        ' Product alias: '.$productAlias.
        ' Product ID: '.$productId;
})->where('productAlias', '([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z]+)');
```

В таком случае вывод будет следующим:

```
Parent category: cat1 
Children category: cat2 
Product alias: 25-rose 
Product ID: 1
```

Так же можете уточнить и другие значения, к примеру что `productId` только число, в документации есть примеры как это сделать.

Comment: Спасибо! Потестил, теперь получается другая проблема: ссылка `/catalog/flowers/roses/52-roses-60sm-5.html` показывает, что `52-roses` - это алиас, а `60sm-5` - это ID. При указании `->where('productId', '([0-9]+)')` выкидывает 404.

Comment: UPD: добавил `([-\w]+)` в регулярку к productAlias, в итоге получился такой: `->where('productAlias', '([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z]+)-([-\w]+)');`.